# Applescript doesn't have write permission to file

Tags: applescript

So I'm trying to write a script that writes any text I want it to to a new file on my Desktop.

```
set the theText to "hello world"
set fileName to "file.txt"
set thePath to "~/Desktop/"
try
    tell application "Finder" to make file at thePath with properties {name:fileName}
end try
set myFile to open for access (thePath & fileName) with write permission
write theText to myFile
close access myFile
```

This code is based on the second most liked answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780985/how-do-i-write-to-a-text-file-using-applescript). When I try to execute the version I have above though, it gives me the error: `"File not open with write permission." number -61 from "~/Desktop/file.txt" to «class fsrf»`. I tried running the code my code is based on and it worked flawlessly. I also tried running it with `choose file` and that also worked. Why is Applescript having problems when working with predefined paths?

Comment: The Finder does not know about POSIX paths.

Comment: @red_menace I've seen similar comments before about the Finder and posix paths but I don't understand it. My understanding is that posix paths are simply file specifiers and are built into applescript — the same as aliases and files. I'm not sure what the Finder has to do with it? You can certainly tell the Finder to work with posix-style references. Note, I'm not questioning the answer, as I agree that the Finder isn't necessary to create a file. Just wondering if you could elaborate on the comment above.

Comment: @Mockman : The OP tried to use the Finder to create a file using a POSIX path - some terminology can use either format, but the Finder uses colon separated HFS paths.  When using the Finder with POSIX paths, the `POSIX file` specifier needs to be used to specify a file using a POSIX path (`System Events` can also be used).  See [Aliases and Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW28) section in the AppleScript Language Guide for more information.

Comment: But isn't that just a syntax issue? The OP's code could have been made to create the file by simply including 'posix file' (putting aside the tilde issue, which required fixing regardless). Again, I agree with the answer but if for example, the intent was to use a shell script to write text and do other stuff, then a posix file approach would have been fine. Framing it this way is kind of ominous-sounding, as though this approach is fraught with peril and doomed to failure. It does work even if there are better approaches.

Comment: @Mockman AppleScript is a relict of pre-OS X times. In System 7–9 there was no UNIX  subbase so there were no POSIX paths. In OS X Apple gradually enabled support for POSIX paths in many APIs like System Events and Scripting Additions but the Finder always stayed in the HFS bubble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments *The Finder does not know about POSIX paths*

But even if it did `open for access` does not know how to expand the tilde, you have to specify the full path.

The Finder is not needed at all to create a file for writing text into. Basically this is sufficient

```
set the theText to "hello world"
set fileName to "file.txt"
set thePath to "/Users/myself/Desktop/"
set myFile to open for access (thePath & fileName) with write permission
write theText to myFile
close access myFile
```

However this is bad practice because the write command could fail and then the file remains in an undefined open state.

The most reliable and user independent syntax is

```
set the theText to "hello world"
set fileName to "file.txt"
set thePath to POSIX path of (path to desktop)
set myFile to thePath & fileName
try
    set fileDescriptor to open for access myFile with write permission
    set eof of fileDescriptor to 0
    write theText to fileDescriptor starting at eof
    close access fileDescriptor
on error
    try
        close access myFile
    end try
end try
```

Comment: It works great, except it doesn't remove the old text that was in the file before and just overwrites it. So if I for example have `"hello world"` and then just `"Dog"`, it won't be `Dog`, it will be `Doglo world`, but I just want it to be `Dog`.